# what happens to variables in tornado coroutines functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, coroutine, tornado-motor

I'm new to the concept of non-blocking IO, and there is something i'm having trouble understanding - about coroutines. consider this code:

```
class UserPostHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        var = 'some variable'
        data = json.loads(self.request.body)
        yield motor_db.users.insert({self.request.remote_ip: data})#asynch non blocking db insert call
        #success
        self.set_status(201)
        print var
```

when the `get` function is called, it creates the string `var`. what happens to this variable when the function waits for the `motor.insert` to complete? To my understanding "non blocking" implies that no thread is waiting for the IO call to complete, and no memory is being used while waiting. So where is the value of `var` stored? how is it accessible when the execution resumes?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The short version is that it's stored in the stack frame for `get`, just as it is in a normal function. The key difference between coroutines and subroutines is that the stack frames don't actually have to be in a stack, they're "put aside" when they hand off control.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Python variables aren't actually storing any data; they're just names for values that live on the heap. So the only thing that's "stored" is the fact that local variable #1 is a reference to some particular object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The memory for `var` is still being used while `insert` executes, but the `get` function itself is "frozen", which allows other functions to execute. Tornado's coroutines are implemented using Python generators, which allow function execution to be temporarily suspended when a `yield` occurs, and then be restarted again (with the function's state preserved) after the yield point. Here's how the behavior is described in the [PEP that introduced generators](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/):

> If a yield statement is encountered, the state of the function is
>   frozen, and the value [yielded] is returned to .next()'s caller. By
>   "frozen" we mean that all local state is retained, including the
>   current bindings of local variables, the instruction pointer, and the
>   internal evaluation stack: enough information is saved so that the
>   next time .next() is invoked, the function can proceed exactly as if
>   the yield statement were just another external call.

The `@gen.coroutine` generator has magic in it that ties into Tornado's event loop, so that the `Future` returned by the `insert` call is registered with the event loop, allowing the `get` generator to be restarted when the `insert` call completes.

Comment: @WeaselFox Cool! If you're interested in the details, you should take a look at the [source for the coroutine decorator](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/gen.py#L116). It takes some time to digest, but (IMO, least) is very interesting stuff.