# How "yield" works in tornado.gen.coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

I read Tornado documentation, and I'm confused with gen.coroutine and how it works. The documentation is here: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#module-tornado.gen
What I cannot understand, is how this piece of code works:

```
class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
    do_something_with_response(response)
    self.render("template.html")
```

How Tornado makes method get() to continue after yield using yield result in function do_something_with_response()? I tried to read source code of function _make_coroutine_wrapper() in tornado.gen module, but still cannot understand this. Can someone explain this in simple terms?

Comment: This question isn't quite a dupe, but might help clarify a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25256461/2073595

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I had not problem with understanding tornado.gen.coroutine, but I forgot Python basics, such as generators behavior. The question might be closed now.